# How to write a geocoder with no external dependencies

Tags: language-agnostic, geocoding

There are services such as [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us) and the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/); however, these are rate limited. How would one go about writing one of these on their own without having to rely on these services (specifically inputing an address and getting a set of coordinates)?

The overall goal would be to calculate the difference in distance between two addresses with a formula like the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). I've used haversine in the past to locate zipcodes within a specific distance of a given zipcode, but now I need to go down to street address level (basically checking if a given address is within a certain range of another given address).

The most obvious thing would be to find a paid service which is not rate limited. Does anybody know of such a service? Writing something like this at street address level seems a lot more cumbersome than zipcode level (especially with new streets being created all the time).

For the time being, I am only focusing on the (Continental) United States.

**Edit:** I just noticed that [geocoder.us is open source](http://search.cpan.org/~sderle/Geo-Coder-US/US.pm). That may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us) imports their data from the available [U.S. Census Tiger/Line® file download](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/). After poking around the internet for a while I found a project called JGeocoder with details on [importing data](http://jgeocoder.sourceforge.net/import.html) from the census and [geocoding based on that data](http://jgeocoder.sourceforge.net/geocoder.html).

Answer (score 0):

At our company, we use Microsoft's MapPoint API.  A WebService which returns Lat/Lon, and even tries to offer a precise address.

This link gives an example call: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545004.aspx

I *think* we pay a fixed rate each month (I work for a fairly big company, so maybe we get a bulk deal - but I don't think we do.)
And the results that it returns are totally fine and accurate.  Both in the US and internationally.

I think they've rebranded it under Bing atm.